# What to do after:" No sd-ext found. Skipping backup of sd-ext"?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, motorola-defy

I want to update to cyanogenMod 9. But before doing this, I've done a nandroid backup.
After the backup was created I saw this output:

```
ClockwordMod Recovery v2.5.1.8
SD Card space free: 1296MB
Backing up system...
Backing up data...
Backing up .android_secure
Backing up cache
No sd-ext found. Skipping backup of sd-ext.
Generating md5 sum...

Backup complete!
```

I'm not sure, but I believe this means that the external sd-card partition wasn't backuped.
Will this be a real problem, if I want to backup my phone? And how shall I solve it, if it's a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means you do not have an ext3/4 partition on your sdcard. This really ins't a big deal, this is like a legacy part of the nandroid backup process. CM doesn't "officially" support the sd-ext partition any more anyhow.

Comment: OK, but what shall I do now?

Comment: @theWorm You can proceed as normal, CM won't touch your external card.  Any ROM that does is messed up.

Comment: Am I able to read and write my files on this sd-card, with cyanogenmod???

Comment: yes, it will have access to read/write to the sdcard.  The normal functionality of the sdcard still exists in CM. The sd-ext partition was to give more space on older devices that only had like 500mb of total storage on the device. This allowed the device to be able to support installing more/larger apps. Even if you had the sd-ext partition, there would still be space left over for the "normal" sdcard partition.

Comment: I have same problem with my rooted LG P500 running stock 2.3.3 with 2nd partition formatted as FAT32.  Will ROM manager (NAndroid backup) work with FAT32?

Answer (score 0):

Your SD card did not get backed up.  If you have a system failure that does not affect your SD card, then your restore will be OK provided that your SD card has not changed substantially since you backed up.  Otherwise, you'll be lacking the part of your apps that is installed to the SD card (which could be almost everything other than the data).

My own approach to this is to make a backup of my entire SD card to my PC immediately after backing up with CWM.  Then I will be able to restore whatever might be changed or missing if and when I need to restore from backup.

"irish Pancake" in this thread seems to have figured it out:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1582248

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove your SIM card(s), not SD card.
2. Do a factory reset,wipe cache and format your android system.
3. Now restore your Nandroid backup.

Comment: How does this help? Please elaborate.